# Playing video using mplayer

Tags: python, linux, video

I want to play an online video using mplayer. I have written a very simple python code to implement it.

```
import os
link="https://www.someurl.com/somevideo.mp4"
os.system("mplayer -fs link")
```

I know this is the wrong way of doing it. I would like to know how can I pass my **link** to the os.system() function.

In my main program, I am receiving random video URLs after specific time intervals which needs to be played from my Linux based device.

Comment: Can you tell me my what version of Python you are using? It will help me answer your question

Comment: I am using Python3. Btw I got the answer .. posted it below.. but if you have any other solution .. I'll highly appreciate it.

Comment: @I am still working on it, but it's great you have got a solution :)

Comment: .... it seems my code keeps on showing error, since you have already got the answer, i guess i will work on my code later sometime

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer .. just posting it for others ...

```
import os
link="https://www.someurl.com/somevideo.mp4"
cmd = "mplayer -fs %s"%(link)
os.system(cmd)
```